# Android Delete Sim Contacts By Id

Tags: android, contacts

How to delete Android sim contacts by id. I have tried so many things but i am not getting any results.

Here is my code it will be great if someone can help me:

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://icc/adn"), "id=?",
                                              new String[] { id }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete local and synced contact. 
You may not use the right raw_contact_id .

I have succeeded doing this in an application using batch operations.
have a look at some syncadapter 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html

Comment: I am not using contacts provider here because i want to delete only sim contacts by id and they are not synced until u import from sim. So here is the reference link from which i found how to delete sim contacts. So please i request you to refer it. [link](stackoverflow.com/questions/25257671/how-to-delete-contacts-from-sim-in-android)